# How to access Environment Variable from AWS in my spring boot application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am working on application which is deployed on AWS. I have set database configuration (`URL`, `UserName`, `Password`) in AWS Environment properties.

[image: AWS environment Variables]

Now how can I access these variables in my spring boot application?

My `application.properties` file looks like:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = <DRIVER>
spring.datasource.url = <URL>
spring.datasource.username = <USERNAME>
spring.datasource.password = <PASSWORD>
```

Note: Currently I am accessing database details from `application.properties` file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use environment variables in spring boot application.properties you can use the usual Spring placeholder notation:

```
spring.datasource.url = ${JDBC_CONNECTION:default_value_connection}
```

Further explanation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-placeholders-in-properties

You can set JDBC_CONNECTION value in AWS Elastic beanstalk. If JDBC_CONNECTION environment variable not set it will use the `'default_value_connection'`.

Comment: I just tested this out to make sure: if your datasource url is somehing like 'jdbc:mysql://endpoint/db', this still works. {JDBC_CONNECTION:jdbc:mysql://endpoint/db}

Comment: For everyone using the YAML file instead of the proprieties file: don't forget to use the double quotes

spring:
  datasource:
  url: "${JDBC_CONNECTION:default_value_connection}"