# Fallback option in Spring application properties in AWS

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a REST service built with Spring Boot where I'm using an `application.yml` file to set up environment variables. The REST service will be deployed to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. I have set up `Environment Properties` in the configuration for the Environment (`Configuration -> Software Configuration -> Environment Properties`)

[image]

I would like for the REST service to pick up the environment variables from AWS Environment Properties when they are available and then use environment variables specified in the `application.yml` file when the Environment Properties are not available as a fallback.

```yaml
spring:
  profiles: default
  datasource:
    type: org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbDataSource
    driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/someDB
    username: someUserName
    password: somePassword
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that I wouldn't have to change the profile used in `application.yml` when I deploy on AWS or do development locally.

I've tried this which doesn't work

```yaml
spring:
  profiles: aws
  datasource:
    type: org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbDataSource
    driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    url: ${ADDRESS_FOR_RDS:jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/someDB}
    username: ${USERNAME:someUserName}
    password: ${PASSWORD:somePassword}
```

Trying to specify as `${AWS_PROPERTY_NAME:FALLBACK_OPTION}` as per [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46091110).

I have been able to get this working using Spring profiles, per [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616279).

Comment: is **url: ${ADDRESS_FOR_RDS:jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/someDB}** what you really have in the configuration file or is it copy/paste mistake?

Comment: @TheOni That is what I really have, trying to use `ADDRESS_FOR_RDS` as the Property name for the value setup in the Environment Properties on aws EB and `jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/someDB` as the fallback.